# BackPressure Exception in RxJava code even after applying proper operator

Tags: java, android, exception, rx-java, backpressure

I am using RxJava in my android application. I am using a timer using the interval() function but I'm getting a Missing Backpressure exception even though I have added onBackPressureDrop(). I have also added onError() to my subscriber and am logging the exception to Crashlytics but it still crashes. Please help. I have spent a week in figuring out the problem but to no avail. The code crashes sporadically and I have not been able to reproduce it even once. TraceonError has been taken directly from an official issue on rxjava git. I think it is the one responsible for printing Crashlytics exception though I maybe wrong.

My delay Observable -

```
serviceStartSubscription = Observable.just(1)
                .delay(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .onBackpressureDrop()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e("Service", "Service not started");
                        Crashlytics.logException(throwable);
                        Crashlytics.log("Error while starting service in Orders Home class");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                        iOmsOrdersHomeScreenActivity.startService();
                    }
                });
```

My observable -

```
public static Subscription createTimer(long expiryTime, @NonNull Subscriber<Long> subscriber) {
    return Observable.interval(1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .onBackpressureDrop()
            .lift(traceOnError())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

traceonError()-

```
public class OperatorTraceOnError<T> implements Observable.Operator<T, T> {

    private final StackTraceElement[] trace = new Throwable().getStackTrace();

    public static <T> OperatorTraceOnError<T> traceOnError() {
        return new OperatorTraceOnError<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(Subscriber<? super T> child) {
        Subscriber<T> parent = new Subscriber<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                child.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                child.onError(new TracedException(throwable, trace));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(T subscriber) {
                child.onNext(subscriber);
            }
        };

        child.add(parent);
        return parent;
    }

    private static class TracedException extends RuntimeException {
        public TracedException(Throwable throwable, StackTraceElement[] trace) {
            super(throwable);
            setStackTrace(trace);
        }
    }
}
```

Crash -

```
Caused by rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException
rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call (InternalObservableUtils.java:386)
rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call (InternalObservableUtils.java:383)
rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onError (ActionSubscriber.java:44)
rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError (SafeSubscriber.java:157)
rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError (SafeSubscriber.java:120)
rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated (OperatorObserveOn.java:276)
rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call (OperatorObserveOn.java:219)
rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run (ScheduledAction.java:55)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
Caused by rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException
rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.onNext (OperatorObserveOn.java:162)
rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.onNext (OperatorSubscribeOn.java:53)
rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTimerPeriodically$1.call (OnSubscribeTimerPeriodically.java:52)
rx.Scheduler$Worker$1.call (Scheduler.java:134)
rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$2.call (EventLoopsScheduler.java:187)
rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run (ScheduledAction.java:55)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:422)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#0
MarketingHandler
 Raw Text
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
#1
FirebaseWorker
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#2
AsyncTask #3
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#3
RxScheduledExecutorPool-1
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#4
OkHttp ConnectionPool
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
okhttp3.ConnectionPool$1.run (ConnectionPool.java:65)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#5
Binder_2
 Raw Text
dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (NativeStart.java)
#6
ManifestHandler
 Raw Text
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
#7
RxIoScheduler-10
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#8
RxIoScheduler-11
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#9
AsyncTask #2
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#10
Okio Watchdog
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:364)
okio.AsyncTimeout.awaitTimeout (AsyncTimeout.java:311)
okio.AsyncTimeout.access$000 (AsyncTimeout.java:40)
okio.AsyncTimeout$Watchdog.run (AsyncTimeout.java:286)
#11
RxComputationScheduler-2
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#12
AnalyticsHandler
 Raw Text
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
#13
Crashlytics Exception Handler1
 Raw Text
dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace (VMStack.java)
java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces (Thread.java:521)
com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeSessionEvent (CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:1009)
com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeFatal (CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:766)
com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleUncaughtException (CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:262)
com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.access$100 (CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:55)
com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$5.call (CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:238)
com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$5.call (CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:235)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun (ExecutorUtils.java:75)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run (BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#14
RxComputationScheduler-4
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#15
RxComputationScheduler-1
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#16
RxSchedulerPurge-1
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#17
RxIoScheduler-3
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#18
RxIoScheduler-2
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#19
Binder_1
 Raw Text
dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (NativeStart.java)
#20
main
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get (FutureTask.java:174)
com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.executeSyncLoggingException (CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:44)
com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException (CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:235)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException (ThreadGroup.java:693)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException (ThreadGroup.java:690)
rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run (ScheduledAction.java:66)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
#21
ProfileHandler
 Raw Text
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
#22
RxIoScheduler-12
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#23
pool-4-thread-1
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#24
fifo-pool-thread-0
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run (FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor.java:118)
#25
RxIoScheduler-9
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#26
Queue
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take (PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#27
OkHttp ConnectionPool
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
okhttp3.ConnectionPool$1.run (ConnectionPool.java:65)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#28
RxScheduledExecutorPool-2
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#29
Queue
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take (PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#30
RxIoScheduler-8
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#31
RxIoScheduler-1 (Evictor)
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#32
RxIoScheduler-5
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#33
GC
 Raw Text
dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (NativeStart.java)
#34
Queue
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take (PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#35
AsyncTask #1
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#36
LocationHandler
 Raw Text
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
#37
ReferenceQueueDaemon
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#38
RxComputationScheduler-3
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#39
Compiler
 Raw Text
dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (NativeStart.java)
#40
TubeSockWriter-2
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketWriter.writeMessage (WebSocketWriter.java:126)
com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketWriter.runWriter (WebSocketWriter.java:141)
com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketWriter.access$000 (WebSocketWriter.java:22)
com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketWriter$1.run (WebSocketWriter.java:36)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#41
RxIoScheduler-6
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#42
FinalizerDaemon
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#43
Signal Catcher
 Raw Text
dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (NativeStart.java)
#44
Binder_3
 Raw Text
dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (NativeStart.java)
#45
RxIoScheduler-7
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#46
Queue
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take (PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#47
StethoListener-main
 Raw Text
android.net.LocalSocketImpl.accept (LocalSocketImpl.java)
android.net.LocalServerSocket.accept (LocalServerSocket.java:94)
com.facebook.stetho.server.LocalSocketServer.listenOnAddress (LocalSocketServer.java:85)
com.facebook.stetho.server.LocalSocketServer.run (LocalSocketServer.java:74)
com.facebook.stetho.server.ServerManager$1.run (ServerManager.java:40)
#48
Answers Events Handler1
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun (ExecutorUtils.java:75)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run (BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#49
RxIoScheduler-4
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#50
AsyncTask #4
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#51
FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#52
TubeSockReader-2
 Raw Text
com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read (NativeCrypto.java)
java.io.DataInputStream.readFully (DataInputStream.java:99)
com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketReceiver.read (WebSocketReceiver.java:141)
com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketReceiver.run (WebSocketReceiver.java:34)
com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.runReader (WebSocket.java:372)
com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.access$000 (WebSocket.java:30)
com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket$2.run (WebSocket.java:108)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
#53
Queue
 Raw Text
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take (PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take (DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Try putting `onBackPpressureDrop()` after `lift(...)` operator.

Comment: Can you show us the `traceOnError` code? Writing operators correctly is very tricky business.

Comment: Just edited my post. I've added the traceonerror code, also it has been taken from an official rxjava git issue

Comment: Your `OperatorTraceOnError` doesn't compose backpressure properly but without it you shouldn't see `MissingBackpressureException`. Also oddly the crash stacktrace doesn't include any methods of `onBackpressureDrop` so are you sure that you look at the right method?

Comment: Yeah, actually I use just one Observable with timer in my app. So I assumed that this Observable was the source of this error. I have another Observable using delay() operator. Could it be the cause?    i have added the code to the delay() Observable in my post. Other than this I use no other Observable with some 'special' capabilities. Mostly just some map,take, filter and from() functions.

Comment: Also if this is not the case, could you suggest some way to find out which observable is responsible for this crash?

Answer (score 0):

In `OperatorTraceOnError` you are implictly requesting `Long.MAX_VALUE` from upstream. To pass through requests from the child subscriber you need to use a different overload of the `Subscriber` constructor:

```
@Override
public Subscriber<? super T> call(Subscriber<? super T> child) {
    Subscriber<T> parent = new Subscriber<T>(child) {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            child.onCompleted();
        }
...
```